# Regular Expression: omit search string

Tags: regex, search, filesystems, locate

Let's say I'd like to find something specific on a filesystem, but to omit certain directories in the search.

Rather than type `locate string`, I'd like to type `locate string[omit anything which resides in specified directory]`.

So, for example, let's say I want to omit `/usr/share` from the listing.

How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
locate string | grep -v ^/usr/share
```

Or, if you search with `find`, use `-prune`:

```
find / -name \*string\* \( -path '/usr/share' -prune -o -print \)
```